# Exporting a dynamically created function for use in a module

Tags: javascript

I'm relatively new to modern Javascript dependency management.  I'm writing a web app in Typescript and have started to use Jasmine as a unit test framework.

Once I started using Jasmine it became clear I needed to start exporting/importing the classes and functions in my source code files, since there is no HTML page loading all of them via script tags.  This has been fine for my own files, but I am using a third-party library that is provided minified:

- https://currency.js.org/
- https://unpkg.com/currency.js@1.2.2/dist/currency.min.js

I can't seem to get my code running via Jasmine to recognize the existence of the *currency* function defined in this file. I'm guessing it's because the function seems to be dynamically created.

What would be a proper way to export the *currency* function above for use in my own modules?

Comment: How did you install and import this dependency in your app? Is there a corresponding npm module for it?

Comment: My web app is just doing naive old-school <script> tags for everything. So imagine
<script src="currency.js" />
<script src="myFileThatUsesCurrency.js"/>

Comment: When I started using Jasmine, I realized that script tags were not an option anymore, so I started to use exports and imports in my own code.  I hit a roadblock with the above library.

Comment: I think it might not be possible. Assuming that currency function works fine as its a third party library, you might need to create a mock currency function to pass to your tests

Answer (score 1):

That package actually is published on npm (with TypeScript typings included), and I was able to successfully import it as a module in a test application:

```
npm install currency.js
```

Then in your code:

```
import currency from "currency.js"
console.log(currency(1.23).add(.01).format());
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/currency.js

Comment: This has unblocked my work, have an upvote. I will leave the question unanswered as I am still interested to know if there is a way to handle that situation.